# Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick when use Browserify

Tags: javascript, html, browserify

I am trying to use MYSQL NodeJS with BROWSERIFY and face this problem

HTML code

```
<button type="button" onclick="abc()" >xyz</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

connectdb.js code

```
  function abc(){
   con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err; 
   con.query("SELECT * FROM database_nmcnpm_nhom1.users", function (err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   else
    console.log(result)
  
});});}
```

I used browserify like this

> browserify ./connectdb.js -o ./bundle.js

But when i click the button the console show error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Just from the `});});}` at the end it seems as if you (or Browserify) defined `abc` somewhere in a deeply nested scope and not in the global scope reachable from the HTML document's attributes. It would probably make more sense for you to use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include a reference to `connectdb.js` in your HTML? If not, you'll have to add this to your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./connectdb.js"></script>
```

Comment: I included like this and i got error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at connectdb.js:1:13 because i use: require("mysql") in my connectdb.js so i try to use browserify to bundle up that.

Comment: @HuuTuongTu did u tried to add `type="module"` to ur `bundle.js`  and to ur `connectdb.js` script tags ?

Comment: I've tried it but it seem not work. Still got the error: 
>Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0):

I generally used to solve this issue as shown below

```
<button type="button" (click)="methodName()" > submit</button>
```

In Angular